# Is there a RegExp that can identify a custom CSS property with a color/background-image and font-size?

Tags: javascript, css, regex, compilation

I'm creating a custom CSS property `text`, which acts as a shorthand for the `color` and `font-size` properties. In addition, it can accept a `background-image` in place of a `color` - things like gradients and `url()` images. It can also have only a `color`/`background-image` or just a `font-size`. Here's some examples of what it looks like:

```css
text: black;
text: 2rem;
text: black 2rem;
text: linear-gradient(to right, blue, red) 2rem;
text: url("/image.png") 2rem;
text: black xx-small;
```

I need a JavaScript function that can parse through a CSS document for these, and then extract the `color`/`background-image` and `font-size` from each, so I can then use `replace()` to compile to vanilla CSS in my plugin.

So far, I've tried using RegEx with two capturing groups to attempt to extract them. Here's a similar RegEx that I used for another custom property, this one a shorthand for `width` and `height`:

```js
/size:\s*([\d\.]+(?:%|px|em|rem|vh|vw)?)(?:\s+([\d\.]+(?:%|px|em|rem|vh|vw)?))?;/g
```

The problem with the `text` property is that the first capturing group needs to identify colors, gradients, and url()s, which can get quite complicated and is unreliable.

Comment: Don't you create more overhead with this "shorthand" than if you'd be using native CSS proprties?

Comment: I'm doing this as part of a CSS preprocessor project, similar to Less and Sass, but instead of extending the language it also redefines some CSS by providing new properties - https://github.com/project-w3bx/style

Comment: I don't think you can do this entirely with regex. This is because if you were to accept every value that `background-image` accepts, you would not be able to reliably capture matching parentheses, such as when using CSS variables, color functions within functions, etc.

Comment: Several steps are probably required, but each step could potentially use regular expressions. Start with the components which are easiest to identify, which is probably `font-size`. Then whatever is left over at the end is probably your `background-image`.